# Adding to empty doubly linked list in python

Tags: python

I know how to add nodes before and after the head and tail, but I dont know how to add a node to an empty doubly linked list. How would I go about doing this? Thank you.

Comment: That depends on the implementation of a doubly-linked list that you're using -- Python doesn't come with one. But the sensible thing would be to add it exactly the way you would add a node to a non-empty list, except that now it doesn't matter whether you add it to the head or the tail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When inserting into an empty list, make both `head` and `tail` refer to the new node. Also, make sure that the node's `next` and `previous` references are consistent with what the rest of the code is expecting.